# Как определить charset пейджи если он не указан или не верен

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkrequest

Господа! Как пример, можно посмотреть сюда https://www.pravda.com.ua/news/2021/01/16/7280136/. Тут на станице не указан `charset`. Он указан в хидере `QNetworkRequest::KnownHeaders::ContentTypeHeader` как UTF8(кодировка не верная). Если использовать `QTextCodec::codecForHtml` возвращается `Latin1`. Если вытащить заголовок из метаданных и использовать `QTextCodec::fromUtfText` - результат такой-же. Если пытаться перебрать все доступные кодеки из `QTextCodec` и проверять, можно ли конвертировать текст, то
`QTextCodec` скажет, что можно конвертировать как минимум 10 кодировок, хотя мы же понимаем что заголовок, как и другой текст, скорее всего, написан в кодировке Windows-1251. Отсюда вопрос: как найти верную кодировку текста пейджи, если не указан `charset`или он не верный?

Comment: также, как делают все - угадывать (например, частотным анализом) или просто знать, что для некоторых сайтов нужно выставить определенную кодировку и не переживать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если мы знаем язык страницы, конвертим (чем получится) из разных кодировок в какую-то одну (utf8 сойдет), а потом проверяем частоту встречаемости букв - если она совпадет с типичной частотой для русского языка - мы угадали.

Фактически, это эквивалентно криптоанализу шифра простой замены.